# regexp with preg_split doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, regex

I tested here [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com) and it should match, but it doesn't...

```
$tabla_contenido = "ouseout=\"sacarobs();\">06/01/2014&nbsp;10:21</a></td><td align='right'><a class='texto'><b>Pendiente</b></a></td><td align='right'><a class='texto'><b>Pendiente</b></a></td><tr class='eltr' onclick=\"ventana('mostrar_nota_de_pedido.php?nnp=117&ven=152&cli=0001&scl=C07&pr=96244651', 'pedidos_listadoNelson');\" ><td align='right'><a class='texto'>117</a></td><td align='right'><a c";
$tabla_data = preg_split("|<tr([^>.]|\.|\,)*>|", $tabla_contenido);
foreach ($tabla_data as $line){
    echo $line."\n\n\n";
}
```

$tabla_data is empty

Comment: first at all, choose a delimiter that is not a special character. This alternation `([^>.]|\.|\,)*` has no sense, replace it with `[^>]*` .

Comment: I can't belive it was that simple, post it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not escaping the `|` inside your regular expression. The easiest solution is to use a different delimiter, such as `~`:

```
$tabla_data = preg_split("~<tr([^>.]|\.|\,)*>~", $tabla_contenido);
```

Alternatively, you could escape the `|` character with a backslash, i.e. `|` would become `\|`, but it makes your regex a bit unreadable, so I suggest using a different delimiter instead.